# If next ul is hidden want to show next ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to check if next ul in a nested unordered list is visible and if not show that ul.

I am using:

```
$('#treemenu1 li a').on('click', function(e) {
    next("ul").is(':hidden').show(300);
    $('#treemenu1 li a').next("ul").is(':visible').hide(300);
});
```

The HTML

```
<ul id="treemenu1" class="treeview">
    <li><a href="#0">Start</a></li>
    <li><a href="#1">Are your team:</a></li>
    <li class="submenu" id="expandable"><a href="#2">Stakeholder Zen</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#3">What is a Stakeholder?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#4">Why manage stakeholders?</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="submenu"><a href="#6">Managing your stakeholders</a>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#7">Use four simple steps</a></li>
            <li class="submenu"><a href="#8">Identify your stakeholders</a>
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#9">Identification techniques</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#10">Identification tools</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: And your question/problem is?

Comment: You don't need to check if it's hidden, just show it, if it's shown already nothing's going to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var $as = $('#treemenu1 li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $next = $(this).next("ul").toggle(300);
    $as.next("ul:visible").not($next).hide(300);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w9WLr/)

or

```
var $as = $('#treemenu1 li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $next = $(this).next("ul");
    $next.filter(':hidden').stop(true, true).show(300);
    $as.next("ul:visible").not($next).stop(true, true).hide(300);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rTYrs/)

Comment: Neither of them work for me.  I click one of the inner ones, and a whole bunch of stuff collapses, but I can't get "Identification tools" to show again.  (Firefox, Windows)

Comment: Thank you this works nicely apart from when you click <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#9">Identification techniques</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#10">Identification tools</a></li>

Answer (score 1):

you using [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) wrong. `is` returns true or false so you need to wrap it in an if block.

and your first `next` is wrong

```
$('#treemenu1 li a').on('click', function(e) {
    var $ul = $(this).next("ul");
    if ($ul.is(':hidden'))
    {
        ($ul.show(300);
    }

    var $ul2 = $('#treemenu1 li a').next("ul");
    if ($ul2.is(':visible'))
    {
      $ul2.hide(300);
    }
});
```

Or better yet, you don't need to check if it's already shown:

```
$('#treemenu1 li a').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).next("ul").show(300);
    $('#treemenu1 li a').next("ul").hide(300);
});
```

Or even better yet *(now you've created a fiddle showing what you want it to do)*:

```
$('#treemenu1 li a').click(function(e) {
    $(this).next("ul").toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: your second option just opens and closes on click http://jsfiddle.net/decker2/FVwFF/7/

Comment: Your question didn't explain what the second call was supposed to do. You can simplify the entire thing to http://jsfiddle.net/FVwFF/8/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#treemenu1 li a').click(function(e) {  
    $('#treemenu1 li a').next("ul:visible").hide(300);
    $(this).next("ul:hidden").show(300);
});
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbJpj/2/)**

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I couldn't get it to work, but I appreciate you help.